# Using External packages like DBScan in Weka API mode

Tags: java, python, weka

I am trying to use Weka API with Java and Python(using weka-python-wrapper). I want to use

```
weka.clusterers.DBScan
```

here, but I am unable to use it for both Java and python. In the Weka src, they are in the External packages directory. Do I need to do something else for using it?

I am able to use

```
weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans
```

in both the Java and Python mode, and also able to DBScan using the GUI and terminal means my Weka Path and Eclipse JARs are set up correctly.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the correct package installed that contains *DBScan* (I believe it is *optics_dbScan*), then you can use it from python-weka-wrapper.

For [installing a Weka package](http://pythonhosted.org/python-weka-wrapper/api.html#packages), you can use something like this:

```
import weka.core.packages as packages
#packages.refresh_cache()  # uncomment this to query for updates
packages.install_package("optics_dbScan")
```

You need to [tell the JVM](http://pythonhosted.org/python-weka-wrapper/api.html#java-virtual-machine) to include the jars from the packages when starting it:

```
jvm.start(packages=True)
```

From Java, you should be able to load the packages as follows:

```
import weka.core.WekaPackageManager;
...
WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(false);
```

Comment: Great, I missed that! Just a small question, why do I need to install packages for API mode when the weka.jar doesn't need them to function?

Comment: I only mentioned the install via pww, in case you want to install packages automatically. E.g. when running your script on another machine that doesn't necessarily have the required packages already installed.